# why do i have to set utf8 in request?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans, utf-8

I use servlets and JPA with entityManager and JDK 1.8 in a netbeans 8.0.2 project and a glassfish server open source edition 4.1.

My netbeans projects source is set to utf8.

My MySQL database is set to utf8- default collation and all my table too.

I m getting garbarge caracters in my table when i insert new data.

I have these properties in my glassfish-ressource.xml

```
<jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="mysql_mysql_rootPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value="root"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniwiki?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

And theses properties in my persistence.xml

```
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniwiki?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
</properties>
```

but i have to set utf8 like this in my requests

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

all my html pages are set in utf-8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"></meta>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"></meta>
    <meta content="" name="description"></meta>
    <meta content="" name="author"></meta>
    <link href="../../favicon.ico" rel="icon"></link>
```

and all my .jsp page begin with

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

line of my log details

`Config:   Connected: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniwiki?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

what i m missing ?

Comment: Can you also add language parameters of your Server Java VM? if you have...

Comment: what has that to do with JPA? If you need "utf8" for your servlet, restrict your question to that

Comment: i give maximum details to avoid questions on environment

Comment: my langage parameters for my server java jm is fr_FR

Comment: You don't have to set UTF8. You have to set whatever charset you used to write the request.

Comment: Charsets is set to utf8 in html pages and .jsp pages
and System.out.println(request.getCharacterEncoding()); return null.

Comment: Garbage?  Question marks?  Mojibake?  Something else?  Do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` so we can diagnose whether the text was stored correctly.